# wireshark makes network working

Tags: networking, ethernet, wireshark

Have a number of boards with ethernet on it. Some boards have hardware bug. When pinging such boards, not always got answers.

**But** when running wireshark capture mode, have stable network exchange (ping, another tpc/ip softwate), when stopping Wireshark problems occur again.
What's this. How can Wireshark influence so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect Wireshark activates the [promiscuous mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode) of the network card and might help to migitate the problem.

Under Linux you can enable it by running `ifconfig eth0 promisc` and disable it with `ifconfig eth0 -promisc`.

In Windows, it's more complicated of course, but for some network card drivers there is an option in the network card hardware settings. I've also read that it might be possible on the command line, use `netsh bridge show adapter` to find out the adapter number, then use `netsh bridge set adapter 1 forcecompatmode=enable` (`1` to be replaced with the correct adapter number) to set "Forced compatibility mode" (apparently a Windows term for promiscuous mode) on that adapter.

You may also want to check for duplicate hardware MAC addresses on your network.

Comment: Thank you, disabling promiscuous mode in Wireshark really led to the repro. I've found that sometimes packets receiving with an extra byte. My question is answered.